# Mirroring in image vertical from a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, unity-game-engine, zxing.net

I want to create a DataMatrix decoder in C#. I'm using the ZXing.NET libary for this. I already coded a QR decoder with ZXing, but somehow for the DataMatrix decoder i need to mirror the picture to get it successful decoded.

So i have in image (128x128) its data is stored in a byte 1d array. The bytes in the array are representing the color of each pixel, so byte[0] would be the color of the pixel (0/0).

Now i want to mirror the picture and save the mirrored picture in another byte array

Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

Mirror vertically:

```
byte[] MirrorY(int size, byte[] inputArray)
{
    byte[] reversedArray = new byte[inputArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length/size; i++){ 
        System.Array.Copy(inputArray, reversedArray.Length - (i+ 1) * size, reversedArray, i* size, size);
    }

    return reversedArray;
}
```

Mirror horizontally:

```
byte[] MirrorX(int size, byte[] inputArray)
{
    byte[] reversedArray = new byte[inputArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length/size; i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){ 
            reversedArray [i * size + j] = inputArray [(i + 1) * size - j - 1];
        }
    }

    return reversedArray;
}
```